# how to use ButtonCssClass inside pager list in gridView

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, web-applications, gridview, pager

i use Paging inside GridView in asp.net, ex:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvProject" runat="server" SkinID="gvProject" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" ViewStateMode="Enabled" AllowPaging="True" 
    PageSize="20" onpageindexchanging="gvProject_PageIndexChanging">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Counter" HeaderText="Counter" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" ItemStyle-Width="60px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="Title" DataNavigateUrlFields="Address" HeaderText="Title" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" ItemStyle-Width="580px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
</Columns>
<PagerSettings FirstPageText="<<" LastPageText=">>" PageButtonCount="10" Mode="NumericFirstLast" NextPageText=">" PreviousPageText="<" Position="Bottom" />
```

and use NumericFirstLast Mode in PagerSettings.

I want use css class for numeric button in pager list similar ButtonCssClass inside NumericPagerField in DataPager.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [`PagerStyle` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagerstyle.aspx) to set the CssClass for the paging area:

```
    <PagerSettings FirstPageText="<<" LastPageText=">>" PageButtonCount="10" Mode="NumericFirstLast" NextPageText=">" PreviousPageText="<" Position="Bottom" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="YourCSSClassName"/>
</asp:GridView>
```

Note that you can set any of the properties that belong to a [TableItemStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tableitemstyle.aspx) object (BackColor, ForeColor, etc).